# is there a way to trace the real-time function calls of a process without blocking

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

platform:linux

question:trace the real-time function calls of running user process without blocking,for example,process A trace process B's real-time function calls.

i know that GDB or pstack cloud trace process, but they did it with the help of ptrace, ptrace will Suspend the tracked process, so,is there a way to  trace the real-time function calls of a process without blocking or get each push and pop of Stack, i I didn't find the right way.

Comment: Maybe ebpf tracing?

Comment: @wxz i will learn about it ,thanks a lot

Comment: strace -p <pid> ?

Comment: @kofemann thanks a lot，but strace can not be satisfied,it is not  real-time function calls